# Can a rule get current file name?

Tags: rector

To debug / reporting purpose, before a refactor, we need to print the current file name in a rule refactor method.

Here we do a LOT of highly specific filtering, so I need to dump filenames where filter passes BEFORE doing any changes, so rector reporting will not output nothing.

Can a rector rule access current parsed file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found !

in the rule we can use

```
$this->file->getFilePath()
```

Also, in the `refactor` method we can also see line of current node

```
$node->getLine()
```